# Error parsing query with XSoup

Tags: java, xpath, jsoup, scrape, xsoup

I'm trying to parse an html page using xsoup.
This is my code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://appsvr.mardelplata.gob.ar/Consultas07/OrdenesDeCompra/OC/index.asp?fmANIO_CON=2015&fmJURISDICCION_CON=1110200000&fmTIPOCONT_CON=--&fmNRO_OC=&Consultar=Consultar").get();
List<String> filasFiltradas = Xsoup.compile("//div[@id='listado_solicitudes'][//tr[@bgcolor='#EFF5FE'  or @bgcolor='#DDEEFF'] | //div[@class='subtitle']]").evaluate(doc).list();
```

I tested the xpath code with Chrome's "Xpath Helper" extension and it works great, but when I run the code it throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query 'div[@id='listado_solicitudes'][//tr[@bgcolor='#EFF5FE'  or @bgcolor='#DDEEFF'] | //div[@class='subtitle']]': unexpected token at '//tr[@bgcolor='#EFF5FE'  or @bgcolor='#DDEEFF'] | //div[@class='subtitle']'
at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.consumePredicates(XPathParser.java:237)
at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.findElements(XPathParser.java:167)
at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.parse(XPathParser.java:80)
at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.parse(XPathParser.java:412)
at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.combinator(XPathParser.java:114)
at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.parse(XPathParser.java:78)
at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.XPathParser.parse(XPathParser.java:412)
at us.codecraft.xsoup.Xsoup.compile(Xsoup.java:25)
at seminario.Seminario.main(Seminario.java:19)
```

Comment: What version of XSoup do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The xpath is OK for me. This may be a bug in XSoup.

Alternatively, you can convert your xpath into a CSS selector.

```css
div#listado_solicitudes tr[bgcolor~=#(EFF5FE|DDEEFF)],
div#listado_solicitudes div.subtitle
```

#### SAMPLE CODE

```java
Elements divs = doc
            .select("div#listado_solicitudes tr[bgcolor~=#(EFF5FE|DDEEFF)], div#listado_solicitudes div.subtitle");
final List<String> filasFiltradas = new ArrayList<>();
for (Element div : divs) {
   filasFiltradas.add(div.text());
}

System.out.println(filasFiltradas);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
[  
   DEFENSORIA DEL PUEBLO,
   490 23/4/2015 $21.945,00 GRUPO NUCLEO S.A. Compra Directa Varios Proveedores CARGA, DESCARGA Y FLETE POR PARTE DEL PROVEEDOR (Libre de todo gasto adicional y en el destino indicado) // Registrada,
   489 23/4/2015 $4.476,00 GUERRERO PABLO MATIAS Compra Directa Varios Proveedores CARGA, DESCARGA Y FLETE POR PARTE DEL PROVEEDOR (Libre de todo gasto adicional y en el destino indicado) // Registrada,
   H.C.D.,
   1890 19/11/2015 $76.800,00 TELEFONICA DE ARGENTINA S.A Concurso de precios Expte.10034 Dig.4 Año 2015. Cpo.1 Concurso de Precios 98/15 SEGUNDO LLAMADO . Contratacion Servicio de Enlace de Telecomunicaciones con Destino HCD. Período del contrato: desde el 1 de Diciembre de 2015 y por el término de 12 meses. Registrada,
   1217 29/7/2015 $2.618,00 GRUPO NUCLEO S.A. Concurso de precios Exp. 1789 Dig 9 Año 2015 Cpo.1 Concurso de Precios Nº 25/15 segundo llamado."Adquisicion de Cartuchos Toner". Registrada,
   747 27/5/2015 $11.911,92 TELEFONICA DE ARGENTINA S.A Concurso de precios Expediente 17-1-2014 Cpo. 1 Alc.1 Prórroga Concurso de Precios Nro. 92/13. Período: desde el 1ero. de Mayo y hasta el 31 de Julio de 2015, inclusive. Registrada,
   1116 13/7/2015 $34.100,00 MDP SISTEMAS DIGITALES S.R.L. Concurso de precios Expte.4566.Dig 7 . Año 2015. Cpo.1.Garantía mínima del producto: seis (6) meses. Registrada,
   750 27/5/2015 $20.892,00 PRIMERA RED INTERACTIVA DE MEDIOS ARGENTINOS (PRIMA) S.A. Concurso de precios Expte. 2470-9-15. Concurso de Precios Nº36/15. Periodo de Contratacion : 12 meses a contar desde la recepcion definitiva de los trabajos. Registrada,
   905 15/6/2015 $40.250,00 DISTRIBUIDORA ARIES S R L Concurso de precios Expte. nº 2929 Díg.2 Año 2015 Cpo. 1 - Concurso de precios nº 38/15 Registrada, 906 15/6/2015 $6.614,00 DISTRIBUIDORA MAYORISTA EN LIBRERIA S.A Concurso de precios Expte. nº 2929 Díg.2 Año 2015 Cpo. 1 - Concurso de precios nº 38/15 Registrada, 602 6/5/2015 $32.190,00 DISTRIBUIDORA ARIES S R L Concurso de precios Adjudicación conforme Decreto Nº 129/15 del HCD y su correspondiente Decreto modificatorio Nº 134/15 Registrada,
   361 1/4/2015 $50.400,00 HIRSCH EDUARDO JOSE Concurso de precios Expte.16316 Dig.6 Cpo.1 Año 2014. Periodo comprendido entre el 1 de abril de 2015 y el 31 de marzo de 2016 Registrada, 1187 23/7/2015 $26.640,00 BUSTOS GUSTAVO LUIS DOMINGO Licitación Privada Expediente Nro. 16575-0-13 Cpo.1 Alc.1. PRORROGA LICITACIÓN PRIVADA 70/2013 - PERIODO DE LA CONTRATACIÓN: DESDE EL 01 DE JULIO Y HASTA EL 30 DE SEPTIEMBRE DE 2015, INCLUSIVE. Registrada,
   1944 1/12/2015 $15.000,00 AMUNDARAIN MARCELO GERARDO Compra Directa PERIODO DE LA CONTRATACION DESDE EL 1º AL 31 DE DICIEMBRE DE 2015 Registrada, 1909 24/11/2015 $3.970,64 TELEFONICA DE ARGENTINA S.A Compra Directa PERIODO DE LA CONTRATACIÓN : NOVIEMBRE 2015 . Registrada,
   1482 11/9/2015 $11.911,92 TELEFONICA DE ARGENTINA S.A Compra Directa PERIODO DE LA CONTRATACIÓN: DEL 1º DE AGOSTO AL 31 DE OCTUBRE DE 2015 - PAGO PARCIAL MENSUAL SEGÚN RENDICIÓN Registrada,
   788 1/6/2015 $8.179,60 EDITORIAL LA PAGINA SA Compra Directa Registrada,
   730 22/5/2015 $33.097,60 EDITORIAL LA CAPITAL SOCIEDAD ANONIMA Compra Directa Registrada, 450 20/4/2015 $2.200,00 HIRSCH EDUARDO JOSE Compra Directa FECHA: 24 DE MARZO DE 2015 - ACTO CONMEMORATIVO POR EL DÍA NACIONAL DE LA MEMORIA POR LA VERDAD Y LA JUSTICIA A LLEVARSE A CABO EL 24 DE MARZO DE 2015 Registrada, 315 20/3/2015 $7.200,00 HIRSCH EDUARDO JOSE Compra Directa Periodo: Enero, Febrero y Marzo de 2015- Pago mensual. Registrada, 80 9/2/2015 $10.714,40 EDITORIAL LA CAPITAL SOCIEDAD ANONIMA Compra Directa Varios Proveedores Registrada,
   449 20/4/2015 $6.600,30 O A C I S. A. Compra Directa Varios Proveedores Registrada,
   374 7/4/2015 $5.000,50 ROJAS CARLOS MARCELO Compra Directa Varios Proveedores Registrada, 451 20/4/2015 $29.750,00 BERARD PABLO CESAR Compra Directa Varios Proveedores CARGA, DESCARGA Y FLETE POR PARTE DEL PROVEEDOR (Libre de todo gasto adicional y en el destino indicado) // Registrada,
   507 27/4/2015 $1.153,80 DISTRIBUIDORA MAYORISTA EN LIBRERIA S.A Compra Directa Varios Proveedores ARGA, DESCARGA Y FLETE A CARGO DEL TODO GASTO ADICIONAL. Registrada,
   508 27/4/2015 $4.916,60 DISTRIBUIDORA ARIES S R L Compra Directa Varios Proveedores CARGA, DESCARGA Y FLETE A CARGO DEL PROVEEDOR, LIBRE DE TODO GASTO ADICIONAL. Registrada, 623 11/5/2015 $347,00 HENNING JUAN FEDERICO Compra Directa Varios Proveedores Registrada,
   622 11/5/2015 $8.455,00 LIMPA SOCIEDAD ANONIMA Compra Directa Varios Proveedores Registrada, 1901 20/11/2015 $3.320,00 CISNEROS GRACIELA SILVIA Compra Directa Varios Proveedores CARGA, DESCARGA Y FLETE POR PARTE DEL PROVEEDOR (Libre de todo gasto adicional y en el destino indicado) // Registrada, 1861 17/11/2015 $20.940,00 LUIS JOSE SIMIONATO SOCIEDAD ANONIMA Compra Directa Varios Proveedores El adjudicatario deberá presentar muestra de impresión - Registrada,
   1600 23/9/2015 $30.000,00 AMUNDARAIN MARCELO GERARDO Compra Directa Varios Proveedores CON PAGO PARCIAL MENSUAL SEGUN RENDICIÓN- PERIODO DE LA CONTRATACIÓN DESDE EL 1º DE OCTUBRE AL 30 DE NOVIEMBRE DE 2015 . SE ADJUNTA ESPECIFICACIONES DE SERVICIO DE FOTOCOPIADO Registrada,
   1602 23/9/2015 $2.850,00 BERARD PABLO CESAR Compra Directa Varios Proveedores Registrada, 1601 23/9/2015 $4.500,00 CAVALLE ROBERTO SANTIAGO Compra Directa Varios Proveedores DEBEN ESTAR REALIZADAS Y ENTREGADAS ANTES DEL 1º DE DICIEMBRE DE 2015 Y LA NÓMINA SERÁ PROVISTA POR EL H.C.D Registrada,
   1453 8/9/2015 $2.750,00 ARMEDENHO HUGO ALBERTO Compra Directa Varios Proveedores DEBERA PRESENTAR PARA SU APROBACION, PRUEBA DE IMPRESION Y CALIDAD DEL PAPEL. COORDINAR LA MISMA AL 4996252, SRA. NORMA VILCHES. ARCHIVO DIGITAL ESTÁ A DISPOSICIÓN EN EL H.C.D. Registrada, 1313 14/8/2015 $5.500,00 LUIS JOSE SIMIONATO SOCIEDAD ANONIMA Compra Directa Varios Proveedores DEBERA PRESENTAR PRUEBA DE IMPRESIÓN Y PAPEL EN EL H.C.D Registrada, 
   1036 30/6/2015 $3.897,00 AUDIO & VISION SONIDO E ILUMINACION S.R.L. Compra Directa Varios Proveedores CARGA, DESCARGA Y FLETE POR PARTE DEL PROVEEDOR (Libre de todo gasto adicional y en el destino indicado) // Registrada
]
```

Comment: Only reason of using Xsoup is to let user use Xpath as selector instead of CSS selector which is default support in Jsoup.

You are suggesting here to use CSS selector which defeats the purpose of using Xsoup.

Comment: @OmSao If Xsoup did work there would be no CSS workaround offered.