# I am unable to create Element through xpath in java using Xoup

Tags: java, selenium, jsoup

**locator**: `//div[contains(.,'Last Login')][@class='exact']`

**Code**:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());

Elements elements = Xsoup.compile(locator).evaluate(doc).getElements();
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.CombiningEvaluator$And.matches(CombiningEvaluator.java:53)  
at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.CombiningEvaluator$And.matches(CombiningEvaluator.java:53)     
at org.jsoup.select.Collector$Accumulator.head(Collector.java:42)   
at org.jsoup.select.NodeTraversor.traverse(NodeTraversor.java:30)   
at org.jsoup.select.Collector.collect(Collector.java:24)    
at us.codecraft.xsoup.xevaluator.DefaultXPathEvaluator.evaluate(DefaultXPathEvaluator.java:25)
```

Comment: https://github.com/code4craft/xsoup/issues/29#start-of-content

Comment: similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732494/error-parsing-query-with-xsoup